# How to create Web user auth token for Sinch?

Tags: javascript, php, sinch

I would like to create an `authTicket` for use with the Sinch Web SDK, as described in the docs ([Authentication by your backend](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/javascript/#authenticationbyyourbackend)).

For the server-side code required to do this, Sinch provides at least two examples:

- https://github.com/sinch/sinch-js-ticketgen
- https://github.com/sinch/php-auth-ticket

The first step is JSON encoding. However, if I run this in JavaScript or PHP respectively, I get different results:

**JavaScript `JSON.stringify(userTicket)`**

```
{
  "applicationKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "identity":{"type":"username","endpoint":"johndoe"},
  "created":"2017-04-12T12:34:56.789Z",
  "expiresIn":86400
}
```

**PHP `json_encode($userTicket)`**

```
{
  "identity":{"type":"username","endpoint":"johndoe"},
  "expiresIn":86400,
  "applicationKey":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "created":"2017-04-12T12:34:56.789Z"
}`
```

(Please disregard the whitespace, this has to do with StackOverflow formatting. I'm asking about order of keys.)

Later, this output is supposed to go into a hash function. Since both JSON strings have the keys in different order, both inputs won't possibly result in the same hashed output.

What is the correct algorithm to compute the authTicket, especially when it comes to the JSON encoding part?

Comment: https://github.com/sinch/php-auth-ticket

Comment: @cjensen Using this example, I always get the "40105 UserTicket expired" error when passing the ticket to the Sinch API in the frontend, even though the `created` and `expiresIn` values should be OK.